# Programatically triggering event into the $timeout cause infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have template that looks like this (with many instances in template like this):

```
<span>
  <button type="button" ng-click="uploadPdf($event)">
    <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
    <input type="file" class="pdfDoc" ng-show="false">
  </button>
</span>
```

The idea is when user click on button, the `input[type="file"]` should be triggered (clicked).

I tried firstly to make It like this:

```
$scope.uploadPdf = function(e) {
  e.currentTarget.lastElementChild.click();
};
```

And It works, but console yell on me that $apply is still in progress, so I found solution where usage of `$timeout` is suggested, so I wrapped code above to `$timeout`

```
$scope.uploadPdf = function(e) {
  $timeout(function() {
    e.currentTarget.lastElementChild.click();
  }, 0, false);
};
```

And this for some reason runs infinitely.

Does anyone why is that happening and any another possible solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check what element was clicked, and if it was input - do nothing

```
$scope.uploadPdf = function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input'){
    return false;
  }
  e.currentTarget.lastElementChild.click();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You click the button with onclick UploadPdf

2) You trigger a click inside the button (on its child element)

3) The click event bubbles back up to the button

4) Go to point 1 :)

And the solution can be

```
ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"
```

applied to the input element